# VBA IsNumeric fails on specific strings?

Tags: vba, isnumeric

Can anyone please help tell me why below expression in immediate box shows the result as True?

? IsNumeric("1d11")

? IsNumeric("5000d110")

Thank you.
Lei

Comment: These numbers are both valid [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers. Use `If VarType(Evaluate("5000d110")) = vbDouble` to check whether a string is a valid base 10 number.

Comment: Thank you Florent, this make perfect sense and solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these values are valid hexadecimal numeric values. That is why the result is true.